# T-SQL WHERE (Column & Value) != 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can someone tell me what this WHERE clause means?

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.vw_EnrollSchedule 
WHERE (dbo.vw_EnrollSchedule.AdEnrollRegistrationStatus & 513) != 0
```

The `vw_EnrollSchedule` view has a column `AdEnrollRegistrationStatus` which is of integer datatype, `NOT NULL` column, and has a default value of zero, so will either be 0 or some value.

What does the

```
dbo.vw_EnrollSchedule.AdEnrollRegistrationStatus & 513
```

portion of the statement accomplish?

Just wondering about the syntax.

Comment: This is a [*bitwise and*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) - presumably the column contains properties stored as bits.

Comment: In SQL Server 2022 you could write this as `GET_BIT(AdEnrollRegistrationStatus ,0) = 1 AND GET_BIT(AdEnrollRegistrationStatus ,9) = 1` - the `513` is `SELECT POWER(2,9)|POWER(2,0)`

Comment: What does the `& 513` supposed to do?

Comment: Actually I just noticed my comment above has an error. It is checking `!=0` so it is just checking that **either** of those two bits are set - not that both of them are. So equivalent to `WHERE 1 IN (GET_BIT(AdEnrollRegistrationStatus ,0), GET_BIT(AdEnrollRegistrationStatus ,9))`

Answer (score 0):

& is a logical AND operation.
So it looks like it's testing some binary bits are set in the integer value. That's bit 1  and bit 10.   The decimal value of that is  513   (512+1).

Applications sometimes use binary bits  because you can pack 8   yes / no or true false values into each byte.    Each  T-SQL integer is usually 32 bits  so that's quite a lot of flags you can pack into one single value.

The application will define what those bits actually signify however.

Comment: **bitwise** and **not** logical and!

Comment: Or bits `0` and `9` as they are often numbered.  ([LSb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Bit_significance_and_indexing) being bit `0`.)